# autobench in ubuntu 8.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu-8.10

I'm using ubuntu 8.10.  I want to do benchmarking using autobench. 
I could install httperf by the command 
**sudo apt-get install httperf**
I thought I should be installing autobench in the same way using **apt-get**. 
But the package was not found. 
Can anybody please suggest me what should I be doing in order make this "autobench" command work for me in ubuntu?  Any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that it is not packaged in which case you have to install from source yourself, or find someone to package it for you.

Looking at the [autobench page](http://www.xenoclast.org/autobench/) it seems as if the author actually provides not only sources but also Debian packages. This makes it likely that he already includes a 'build recipe' (i.e. a `debian/` subdirectory). This way you can learn how to create a local .deb package which is useful thing to know.

Answer (score 2):

You have .deb packages available on [autobench homepage](http://www.xenoclast.org/autobench/), just download the version you want and install it using

```
sudo dpkg -i <the_deb_file>
```